# Survive configuration change for a data class with a toggle variable

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I have a ***data class with a 'checked' variable***. The purpose of this variable is to change the icon displayed when clicked or not.

This worked fine but **I have a issue if I rotate the screen or split the screen** with another app; **the *checked variables becomes unchecked***.

> I understand ***rememberSaveable* works well for configuration
> change** but **I have no idea how to use it here with a list of data
> class** or possibly, a better approach to solve this issue.

This is what I am trying to avoid, the checked icon becoming unchecked upon rotation **(image below)**

**(There is the code below image)**

**I will really appreciate an explanation to your suggested solution.**

[image]

```
data class Person(val name: String, val age: Int, val initialChecked: Boolean = false) {
    var checked: Boolean by mutableStateOf(initialChecked)
}

@Composable
fun PersonElement(person: Person, onClick: () -> Unit) {
    var image = if (person.checked) Icons.Default.CheckCircle else Icons.Default.Person
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(16.dp)
            .clickable { onClick() },
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
    ) {
        Icon(imageVector = image, contentDescription = null)
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(16.dp))
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
        ) {
            Text(
                text = person.name,
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleMedium.copy(fontSize = 17.sp)
            )
            Text(
                text = person.age.toString(), modifier = Modifier.alpha(.7f),
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.labelLarge.copy(fontSize = 15.sp)
            )

        }
    }
}


@Preview
@Composable
fun itemSelection() {
    var context = LocalContext.current
    var mockList = listOf<Person>(
        Person("Adebayo Salami", 57),
        Person("Musa Danjuma", 23),
        Person("David Fida", 28),
        Person("Otondo Kowope", 84),
        Person("Olushola", 14),
        Person("Opeloyeru", 34)
    )
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        for (person in mockList) {
            PersonElement(person = person) {
                person.checked = !person.checked
               // Toast.makeText(context, "Person Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `mockList` isn’t remembered.

Comment: The problem persists even if you add a list to the remember. You need to hold data when change rotation because composable will recreate. Solution is viewModel to protect data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation is you need to use viewModel. Here is example viewModel:

```
class ExampleViewModel(): ViewModel() {
val mockList = mutableStateListOf(
        Person("Adebayo Salami", 57),
        Person("Musa Danjuma", 23),
        Person("David Fida", 28),
        Person("Otondo Kowope", 84),
        Person("Olushola", 14),
        Person("Opeloyeru", 34) )
}
```

And you need to implement the viewModel like that:

```
@Composable
fun itemSelection(viewModel: ExampleViewModel = androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.viewModel()) {
    var context = LocalContext.current
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        for (person in viewModel.mockList) {
            PersonElement(person = person) {
                person.checked = !person.checked
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't have library for viewModel, you can use this:

```
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.5.1"
```

Call your composable view with empty parameter. Here is example:

```
setContent {
        ExampleTheme {
            Surface(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                color = MaterialTheme.colors.background) {
                itemSelection() // True
                itemSelection(viewModel = ExampleViewModel()) // Wrong
            }
        }
}
```

**ViewModel benefits:**
The alternative to a ViewModel is a plain class that holds the data you display in your UI. This can become a problem when navigating between activities or Navigation destinations or change rotation. Doing so destroys that data if you don't store it using the saving instance state mechanism. ViewModel provides a convenient API for data persistence that resolves this issue.

Comment: I appreciate the effort in explaning it to me. It worked.